# Who wrote "the traditional Conservative melody" to Adon Olam?

Tags: music, provenance

Who wrote "the traditional Conservative melody" to Adon Olam? It's the third recording on this page: http://zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=23#rec (you have to click "Load recordings" to see the list)